# Why do some of my blueprints stop working?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

Every once in a while, some of the blueprints in my UE4 project will stop working. When I try to open them, I get this screen:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3giN.png)
I have found no way to fix this except remaking the blueprint from scratch. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this problem happens, but it might be just a Mac problem.

The solution is clicking
Window -> Class Defaults -> Open Full Blueprint Editor.
(On the top menu bar)

Hope this helped. I got the answer from [Epic Game's Forums](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/blueprints-not-showing-any-content-in-ue-4-24/139526)

Comment: Thanks! I'm not on Mac but it still works.